# Uneven spacing between textboxes

Tags: html, css, forms, textbox

I have made a form in html. It's very subtle but I think there is uneven spacing between my text boxes and I'm not sure why:

[image]

I believe that the second gap is a couple of pixels wider than the first gap.

I am learning and think it would be instructive for me to figure out why.

**The Relevant HTML:**

```
  <span class="span1">
    <span class="date">
      Year:<br><br>
      <input class="textbox1" type="text" name="year" placeholder="yyyy">
    </span>
    <span class="date">
      Month:<br><br>
      <input class="textbox1" type="text" name="month" placeholder="mm">
    </span>
    <span class="date">
      Day:<br><br>
      <input class="textbox1" type="text" name="day" placeholder="dd">
    </span>
  </span>
```

**The Relevant CSS:**

```
.span1{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    padding-top: 63px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.date{
    display: inline-block;
}

.textbox1 {
    width: 70px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: They are the exact same width apart for me in this example https://jsfiddle.net/o0u3y047/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding float to the date class and then add a margin. Example:

```
  .date{
      display: inline-block;
      float: left;
      margin-right: 5px;
  }
```

[Plunk Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/JP9Nb1swPBkQ2bPie8T4?p=preview). Hope it helps!